# Java - Creating a multiple line english to pig latin translator

Tags: java, string, split

Disclaimer: This is HW but it isn't making much sense to me. I have 2 classes PigDriver and Piglatin. I must use String split and can not use Arraylist.

PigDriver:

```
import java.util.*;
public class PigDriver{
  public static void main(String[] args){
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String t = " ";
Piglatin p = new Piglatin();
while(t.length() > 0){
  t = scan.nextLine();
  t = t.toLowerCase();
  p.pigConvert(t);
}
p.pigReport();
 }
}
```

Piglatin:

```
public class Piglatin{
// declare a data structure to store lines of text
String[] latin = {" "," "," "};
String s = " ";

public Piglatin (){
   // initialize the data structure you declared above to be empty
   latin[0] = s;

}

public void pigConvert(String q){
     // store each line
  String[] line = q.split("[ ,.!?;:]");
  System.out.println(q +" 1");
  for(int s=0; s<line.length; s++){
     System.out.println(line[s] +" Space");
  }


  s = q;
     /*if a word begins with a vowel (a-e-i-o-u), then "ay" is added to the end of the word 
     (so idle -> idleay, and often -> oftenay); on the other hand, if a word begins with a 
     consonant, then the first letter is removed, and is placed at the end of the word, 
     followed by "ay" (so month -> onthmay, and castle -> astlecay).*/
  char test;
  String spot = "";
  for(int i=0; i<line.length; i++){
     spot = line[i];
     test = spot.charAt(0); 
     if(test == 'a' || test == 'e' || test == 'i' || test == 'o' || test == 'u'){
        line[i] = spot + "ay";
        System.out.println(line[i] +" 3");
        }
     else{
        line[i] = spot.substring(1) + spot.charAt(0) + "ay";
        System.out.println(line[i] +" 5");
        }
  }
  for(int y=0; y<line.length; y++){
     latin[0] = line[y]+" ";
     System.out.println(latin[0]+" 6");
  }
}

public void pigReport(){
    //just print the lines
   for(int y=0; y<latin.length; y++){
     //System.out.println(latin[y]);
     System.out.println("banana");
     }
}
```

}

On this input:

```
Now is the time,
for all good, and I mean very good men and women,
to visit their grandmothers!
```

The following output was produced:

```
ownay isay hetay imetay 
orfay allay oodgay anday iay eanmay eryvay oodgay enmay anday omenway 
otay isitvay heirtay randmothersgay
```

I realize how messy it is but would appreciate any help

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: If you don't understand the assignment, you should contact your instructor. If you understand the requirements but are completely lost, again, contact your instructor. If you're not completely lost, then please strive ask a much more specific and answerable question.

Comment: My main error is    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0      When i run it it highlights          test = spot.charAt(0);    and         p.pigReport();        as the issue. It compiles but always produces this error when run.

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are stuck with debugging your code.  We are not here to do this for you ...

However, here are some hints to get you started.

1. (Always) read the exception message:

   ```
     StringIndexOutOfBoundsException String index out of range: 0
   ```

   What is it actually saying?

   What does the javadoc for the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` class say about it?
2. The exception occurred in this expression: `spot.charAt(0)`.  We can conclude from this (and the stacktrace which you didn't show us ...) that the exception was thrown while calling `String.charAt`.

   What does the javadoc for that class say?
3. Assuming that you have done the work of reading the javadocs ... you will find that the problem is that your code has failed at that point because it is attempting to get the first character of a string that contains ZERO characters; i.e. an empty String.

   How did that happen?  Where did the string come from?  Why is it zero length?

   Once again .... read the javadocs!
4. Once you have worked out how / why that happened, think about what you should do about it.

---

I deliberately did not include links to the javadocs.  Your teacher should have told you how to find, search and read them.

Comment: Thank you for the hints they did help and yes my teacher has told me how to find javadocs